# razor - how to dynamicaly insert id into div element

Tags: javascript, razor

In my view I have:

```
@foreach (var comment in Model.commentList)
{
    var id = comment.CommentId;
    <div id="@(id)" style="height:100px; width: 100px; background-color: red; display:none;"></div>
    <a id=@id onClick="ShowForm(this.id)" href="#">Comment</a>
}
```

And then I have a script:

```
function ShowForm(clicked_id) {
    var element = "#" + clicked_id;
    $(element).fadeIn(1000);
}
```

What I want to achieve is to show a certain element after clicking a link but it is not working. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Would you code not set two elements with the same id?

Comment: Ids need to be unique so your jQuery won't work

Comment: Guessing here but  `$(document).on('click','element',function(){$(element).fadeIn(1000);})` putting this line in the ShowForm instead of the last line does it change anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first point is that IDs should be unique - ID means identity, how can you identify something if it is not unique?

This will be probably what is causing your jQuery not to work.  But as you are using jQuery, why not bind your click using jQuery?

What I would do is give your links a class, remove the link id and put it into the href (so that your code will be more accessible) and then bind your click using jquery on document ready:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.link').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();                 // prevent default action of link

      var link = $(this),
          targetId = link.attr('href'),  // get the href of the current link and use it as the id of the element
          targetDiv = $(targetId);

          targetDiv.fadeIn(1000);        // fade in the div
          link.hide();                   // hide the link? not sure if you want to let them click it again
    });
});
```

```razor
@foreach (var comment in Model.commentList)
{
    var id = comment.CommentId;
    <div id="@(id)" style="height:100px; width: 100px; background-color: red; display:none;"></div>
    <a href="#@(id)" class="link">Comment</a>
}
```

Example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.link').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default action of link

    var link = $(this),
      targetId = link.attr('href'), // get the href of the current link and use it as the id of the element
      targetDiv = $(targetId);

    targetDiv.fadeIn(1000); // fade in the div
    link.hide(); // hide the link? not sure if you want to let them click it again
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" style="height:100px; width: 100px; background-color: red; display:none;"></div>
<a href="#test" class="link">Comment</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're setting two elements with the same id

Try changing your cshtml like this

```
@foreach (var comment in Model.commentList)
{
    var id = comment.CommentId;
    <div id="@id" style="height:100px; width: 100px; background-color: red; display:none;"></div>
    <a onClick="ShowForm(@id)" href="#">Comment</a>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The `@` before the `foreach` will cause Razor to interpret the loop contents as C#.

Try prefixing the HTML lines inside the loop with "`@:`", like this:

```
@foreach (var comment in Model.commentList)
{
        var id = comment.CommentId;
        @:<div id="@(id)" style="height:100px; width: 100px; background-color: red; display:none;"></div>
        @:<a id=@id onClick="ShowForm(this.id)" href="#">Comment</a>
}
```

Comment: divs and html will render inside a loop without the need for the `@:` - I've never had to use this syntax